# How to retrieve users logging-in and logging-out date and times in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

At the moment we are using SharePoint 2013 with a few tenants.

We are going to have access to the users logging-in and logging-out dates and times.

For instance, I would like to know the detail of the dates and times which a particular user of a tenant has logged-in and logged-out during the past few months.

Any idea?

Comment: Are you using any sort of FBA? If yes then there is Field in SQL Serer table which takes a record fr this

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything like it in the database, so you probably have to do this yourself. To save the last login time, you can hook into the wp_login action, and save a user meta value (like [myprefix]_lastlogintime). You first read this value, so you get the previous login time, save this in the session, and then save the new login time.

On the regular admin pages you check whether this session variable is set. If it is, you display the welcome text and clear the session variable so you don't display it on every page.

If you want to save the last page visit time you have to write to the database on every (admin) page view. This is possible, but I would not recommend it. You can also save something once on logout (action wp_logout), but probably not everyone will remember to log out.

ALSO ONE KIND OF TOOL IS THERE. please go through this link
http://blog.muhimbi.com/2011/06/reporting-site-collection-level-user.html

Comment: Actually I have a task to retrieve this information for the past year. I thought may be SharePoint keeps this sort of information somewhere.